# Trying to get an struct initializer from a tertiary operator in a macro function doesn't work

Tags: c, macros, initialization, conditional-operator, initializer-list

Trying to get an struct initializer from a tertiary operator in a macro function doesn't work, it gives a bunch of errors, what should be the right way to do this:

```c
#define newVar(name, type, value) (( (type) == _STRING ) ? { name, type, (long)value }) : ({ name, type, (double)value } )
```

Edit:
Sorry, i wrote array initializer and not struct initializer

Comment: Please, for completeness post also the line in which you invoke the macro, and the errors raised by it.

Comment: @Gabryx86_64 This  { name, type, (long)value } is not an expression while the ternary operator expects an expression. So the construction is invalid.

Comment: Right way to do what - what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why would you have type-generic programming inside an array initializer? Is it some sort of `void*` list?

Comment: You could transform an intialitizer list in a compound liter, which is an expression
`(Type){ name, type, (long)value }`. This one could be used in the ternary assuming both return types are the same.

Comment: @tstanisl it did work, but with other things it doesn't have worked, I found out that that can have worked with any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use the ternary (conditional) operator such a way in an initialization because the operator expects three expressions. However these constructions
`{ name, type, (long)value }` and `{ name, type, (double)value }` are not expressions. They are initializer lists.

For example you may write

```
int x = { 10 };
```

but you may not write

```
int x = 1 ? { 10 } : { 20 };
```

because in the ternary operator `{ 10 }` and `{ 20 }` are not expressions.